# archipack boolean command displaces objects

Tags: archipack-add-on

I would like to cut a hole for a door in a wall. When I press the "Boolean" button, my wall and doors get moved. Is it a bug or intended behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

- Blender Version 2.93.2 (2.93.2 2021-08-04)
- Archipack Version 1.2.84

After selecting two objects
[image]

After pressing "Boolean" button on Archipack panel

[image]